# PKIX path building failed: SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target (webrisk.googleapis.com)

Tags: ssl, https, pkix

I'm running a Java application that calls Google Web Risk services using Apache HttpClient.
The app is running on Tomcat 9 server without any special configs.

During the handshake with Google's host, I'm getting the following error

```
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

After some research, I realized the error indicates that probably my JVM truststore doesn't contain the target (Google's host) rootCert.

The target host is https://webrisk.googleapis.com which uses CA "GTS Root R1" cert.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOqMm.jpg)

I looked into my Java truststore and found it there (`keytool -list -keystore /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-11.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts -v`), so it doesn't seem to be an issue with my Java truststore.
In addition to that, while running the same client not from the Tomcat server (E.g, - from a test) I'm NOT getting the error and the client works fine.

That's led me to focus on the way my app is picking up the trustore.

I downloaded the "GTS Root 1 cert" .pem file from https://pki.goog/repository/ and tried loading it programmatically using SSLContext custom configs - that didn't work.

I tried implicity set the -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore AND -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-11.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts` - that didn't work.

Below are the logs of the handshake

```
DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection request: [route: {s}->https://webrisk.googleapis.com:443][total available: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 0 of 20]
DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection leased: [id: 3][route: {s}->https://webrisk.googleapis.com:443][total available: 0; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Opening connection {s}->https://webrisk.googleapis.com:443
DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator - Connecting to webrisk.googleapis.com/142.251.142.202:443
DEBUG org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Connecting socket to webrisk.googleapis.com/142.251.142.202:443 with timeout 0
DEBUG org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Enabled protocols: [TLSv1.3, TLSv1.2]
DEBUG org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Enabled cipher suites:[TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
DEBUG org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Starting handshake
DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-3: Shutdown connection
DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Connection discarded
DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection released: [id: 3][route: {s}->https://webrisk.googleapis.com:443][total available: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 0 of 20]
ERROR com.akamai.csi.pulsar.mitigation.client.GoogleWebRiskRestClient - PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I must say that I googled it and found many solution, non of them worked here. What am I missing?

I tried to load programmatically the gtsr1.pem cert.
I tried to set the point the java properties to my Java truststore.